# Inconstant Maven error when building from command line

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, batch-file

I have several Eclipse projects that I am building using Maven.  It is basically a couple of library jars (because I have shared code), and 4 Google App Engine projects that reference them.  I have setup a Windows batch file to build them all via a Maven command line in sequence as a convenience when building locally to test new code.

I am getting random build failures when running the batch file complaining it can't find a compiler. Oddly enough, if i restart the batch file it will build just fine the 2nd time. The script always fails on projects that have changes, however it isn't always the same project.  I've had it happen to pretty much every project in the chain, and to both the library projects and the GAE WebApp projects as well.  It's weird to me because these projects build correctly about 90% of the time. I should note I am not getting an errors building in Eclipse, however those will only build one at a time.

Here is a redacted snippet of my batch file:

```
@REM Change to the Maven project dir
CD "%BASE_DIR%\[redacted]"
(mvn install 2>&1 & call doskey /exename=err err=%%^^errorlevel%%) | C:\utility\wtee.exe -a "%LOG_FILE%"
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A IN ('doskey /m:err') DO SET RETURN_CODE=%%A
ECHO maven returned %RETURN_CODE%
@IF %RETURN_CODE% gtr 0 GOTO :END
```

And here is the console output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building [redacted] 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ [redacted] ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\[redacted]\git\DEVON\Code\[redacted]\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ [redacted] ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 24 source files to C:\Users\[redacted]\git\DEVON\Code\[redacted]\target\[redacted]-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.139 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-28T14:15:45-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/304M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project [redacted]: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
maven returned 1
```

I have searched and searched here and using Google, but all the suggestions point to an incorrect JDK setup in the project or to Java compiler pathing issues.  However I have checked all of that, and of course the project DOES build right almost all the time, and of course if I simply restart the batch file it works fine.

For reference:

- Using Eclipse 4.5.2 (Mars)
- Using Maven 3.3.9
- Using JDK 1.7.0.80
- All projects are set to "Compiler compliance level" 1.7 (because of GAE)
- Java build path references:

  - Google App Engine 1.9.37
  - JavaSE-1.7

Has anyone seen something like this before? This is an annoyance more than a blocker, however any help to resolving it would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
After adding the -V switch, I noticed that Maven was referencing a jre in the log:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T09:41:47-07:00)
Maven home: C:\Utility\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_92, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: c:\Program Files\java\jre1.8.0_92\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
```

Again the weird thing is this compiles fine like 95% of the time, so it much use the JDK *most of the time* or it would not compile at all...

I've tried changing my java home environment variable to `c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_92` in the batch file to see if that resolves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that somehow your path for Java is not consistent when executing the script.  Try running maven with the `-v` flag.  This will cause it to tell you which Java home and version it is running.  Your java home should be a jdk installation, and not a jre installation.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure HOW it can be inconstant when I am triggering the batch file in a constant way. :-)

However I will try adding the -v flag and monitor, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I tried adding -v, however that just dumps the version info and does not build, so I am not sure how much that helps, but thanks.

Comment: Checked the Maven docs, and changed it to use -V  

    `-V, --show-version
    Display version information WITHOUT stopping build`